# I booked a hotel on my old bank card before I cancelled the card and switched banks

Tags: hotels, payment-cards

I booked a room on my old bank account card; I paid for the room in full on that card. I no longer use that bank account and opened a new bank account through a different bank. Will I have issues checking in, or will I be fine since it's already paid for?

Answer (score 5):

Logic says that if they have your money they have agreed to your stay, so you should be fine. They will probably want a swipe of your new card to cover the possibility of extra expenses during your stay. I had one weird experience checking in once when the hotel was trying to use my credit card as the id to retrieve my booking. Fortunately I had a copy of the hotel's reference number and so they were able to find the reservation. So ensuring you have that might be wise in your situation.

However some hotels have conditions saying that you are required to show the card you used to book when you check in, I assume as a form of ID. I've stayed in hotels with that stated policy and *not* actually been asked for my card. While it seems absurd that there could be any problem providing you have some other ID I would double check by calling the hotel and asking whether there is an issue.